# Do AEAD algorithms and encrypt-then-MAC mitigate external decryption oracles?

Tags: mac, authenticated-encryption, padding-oracle, decryption-oracle

I'm curious about a possible attack scenario that I'm not sure exists. If it is possible, I'd like to know if and how AEAD algorithms and encrypt-then-MAC implementations protect against it.

The attack in question uses a custom-developed decryption oracle on an external system that uses the same parameters as the ones used to create the encrypted message. For example, if the message had been generated using an open source library such as Libsodium, which the adversary utilizes to create an automated oracle on their own hardware.

**Scenario**

Two encrypted messages sent by Alice to Bob are intercepted by Susan. The first was encrypted an AEAD mode of operation (say AES GCM), whereas the second utilized an encrypt-then-MAC flow (say AES CBC + SHA3).

Susan is fully aware of the cryptographic implementation (i.e. algorithm and mode of operation, MAC, *open source* library and version used).

**Question**

Is it possible for Susan to create her own decryption oracle to decipher the plaintext messages with her knowledge and access to both the message payload and implementation library?

Would this oracle be successful against an AEAD algorithm?

Would this oracle be successful against an encrypt-then-MAC implementation? In my mind, the adversary could simply ignore the MAC. **I am especially curious of how one would protect AES CBC against a padding oracle attack in this scenario (if it is a valid one).**

Comment: Susan can do whatever she wants, but if she doesn't have Alice & Bob's secret key, it doesn't matter. Alice & Bob would have to expose a dumb decryption oracle (that ignores the MAC perhaps) in order for things to go wrong.

Comment: I would worry about an encryption oracle. If you can have Bob create a CBC stream of any message *and* you can predict the IV then you can regenerate the key stream used within AES-GCM. Of course, if the transport protocols allow to reuse the key for different schemes then there is something terribly wrong in the first place. But yeah, if different keys are used and those are kept secret, then you'd be out of luck if the system is well implemented.